# Matplotlib toolbar is None in Gitlab Pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am adding a custom tool to matplotlib toolbar:

```
1. self._toolmanger = self._fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager
2. self._toolmanger.add_tool("Custom Tool", CustomTool, toggle=func)
3. self._fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.add_tool(self._toolmanger.get_tool("Custom Tool"), "tool")
```

When I run my code locally everything works fine. But when I run it in a gitlab pipeline I get the following error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_tool' (Line 3)`. Are there any extra dependencies I need to install in the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and found a solution. Gitlab's environment probably uses a backend that lacks a toolbar (as does the `inline` backend that's both Spyder and Jupyter enable by default). Set a backend that has one.

`mpl.use('Qt5Agg')` works for me on Windows

In an IPython session, try `%matplotlib qt` (I think this is platform-independent, but I'm not sure it will work in your Gitlab flow.)